# How do I close a file that I created using cat > command?

Tags: unix, cat

I learning how to use git on a Mac and I'm trying to add a file in one of my branches by using the "cat > " command. The problem I'm having is that I want to end editing the file in the terminal but I do not know how to close it. I'm guessing that I need to change "modes" for lack of a better term. How do I proceed?

Comment: cat is not a text editor! Are you trying to be a masochist? http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it all the time, but I don't see a problem doing that if all you want is to create a 2- or 3-line script.  That's easier than firing up a text editor.

Comment: If you are in a limited environment with no text editor (e.g., testing something inside a container with no root privilege), then you can use it as last resort.

Answer (score 13):

Press Control-D.

Answer (score 13):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the start of a new line. `^D` is the "end of file" character when typed from a keyboard.

Note that the `^D` character itself is not entered into the file. The file ends just before the point where you type `^D`.

Comment: The Enter shouldn't be pressed on Unix-based systems (though MacOS might be an exception?); this isn't DOS where you have to press Enter after ^Z. You may need to press ^D a second time if you aren't already at the start of the line, though.

Comment: Indeed. Why did I think you needed to press Enter? Fixed, thanks.

Comment: `at the start of a new line` - because per POSIX, a line that doesn't end in a newline... isn't actually a line, so a file containing one isn't formally a text file.